# How can I find the area enclosed by the functions in integral?

Tags: integration

How can I find the area enclosed by the following functions using integration ?

**(1)** $y=2x^2, y=x^4-2x^2$

**(2)** $x=y^3, x=y^2$

Comment: One way is wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 2):

**In general:** Say we have two functions, $f(x),g(x)$ which intersect at two points with abscissae, $A,B$. Then, in the interval $(A,B)$ if $f(x)\geq g(x)$, the area between $f(x),g(x)$ is
$$\mathrm{Area}=\int^B_A\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
Hope this helps,

Comment: I guess it should be: two points *with abscissae* A, B...

Comment: @derpy Thanks - I edited my answer.

Comment: How to apply it into the questions? I have no idea about it.

Comment: @CarlJon For a), for example, where do $y=x^2$ and $y=x^4-2x^2$ intersect. Is $x^4-2x^2\geq x^2$ in that interval?

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar  Yes, they should same value because both of them equal to y.